# Select event for a div element

Tags: jquery, html

This is my sample code. The *select* function is not working. What I'm doing wrong here. Browser chrome, OS Windows 7.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  p { color:blue; }
  div { color:red; }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>
    Click and drag the mouse to select text in the inputs.
  </p>
  <div id="b">Some text in div element</div>


  <div id="a"></div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#b").select( function () { 
          $("#a").text("Something was selected").show().fadeOut(1000); 
        });
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery's [`.select`](http://api.jquery.com/select/) works on `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes, not `div`s.

Comment: Is there any other way to implement this functionality for <div> element?

Comment: The New York Times seems to be able to do what you need, but you'll have to figure out how it works: http://graphics8.nytimes.com/js/common/screen/altClickToSearch.js

Comment: You can have a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse

Comment: here's an example of how to do this manually: http://motyar.blogspot.de/2010/02/get-user-selected-text-with-jquery-and.html

Answer (score 2):

```
<div="a"></div>
```

should be

```
<div id="a"></div>
```

Comment: Please see the updated question. Thanks for notifying me but that's a typing error.

Comment: then look at @John Pick's answer.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation:

> "This event is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes."
>   http://api.jquery.com/select/

It won't work for a div.